# Merging 210 sheets into one sheets in one workbook

Tags: database, excel, vba

I have 210 sheets in one worksheet. How could I merge the 210 sheets into one sheet? The first sheet has the data labels as the first row  and the other sheets have data without the labels as the first row. Please help. Thanks

Comment: Please search Stackoverflow. These type of questions (or a variation of it) have been asked previously many times before

Comment: as well as my answer below, maybe you could try the **RDBMerge** addin from [Ron De Bruin Excel MVP site](http://www.rondebruin.nl)

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```
Sub CopySheets()
'
Dim xSheet As Worksheet
Dim oRange As Range
Dim sTargetSheet As String
'
' this is the results sheet name
sTargetSheet = "Sheet2"

For Each xSheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If xSheet.Name <> sTargetSheet Then
        xSheet.UsedRange.Copy
        Worksheets(sTargetSheet).Range("A" & Worksheets(sTargetSheet).Rows.Count).End(xlUp).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

that should get you started.